# Electron Spin, and the Stern-Gerlach Experiment

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, electrons, magnetism, spin

[image][image]I think I understand the basics of the electron spin. However, I'm trying to figure out how to tell if, when shooting a beam of atoms (the Stern-Gerlach experiment), how to tell if an element will have some atoms deflecting up and some down?
I initially thought to draw out the electron distribution of each possible element (it's a multiple choice question) and then try and figure out which ones were spinning up and which were spinning down. But this doesn't align with the answer to the question. Any guidance would be appreciated?

Comment: Your question is a tad unclear. It might help if you include the original question from the source in some way.

Comment: No worries, just added

Comment: That's a terrible question. What is upwards/downwards wrt the orientation of the field? Is there an accompanying drawing?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear myself. It's for a class, and we only touched on this experiment briefly, when we were introduced to electron spin. So I assume I must do something with the electron spin configuration of these elements? Maybe if the electron is spinning in a certain direction it impacts the deflection? But then that doesn't make too much sense because it says the whole atom is deflected

Comment: There are no such things as "spinning up", "spinning down", or "spinning in certain direction". On the other hand, the electron distribution of each element is indeed required. It will tell you which of the atoms have non-zero spin. Those will get deflected, and the rest won't.

Comment: Oh actually, I just noticed there is a picture in my lecture notes, and I think it means the positive spin means upwards deflection. But when I wrote out the Si configuration, the final shell just has two electrons spinning in the same direction? So I'm not sure how there would be variation in deflection

Comment: Okay Ivan, but the question says some atoms will get deflected UP and some DOWN, so how do you differentiate which go up and which down?

Comment: We don't. Nor does the question ask that.

Comment: Ohh, I just noticed the other elements have full outer orbitals. So is it just the fact that Si happens to have a net spin, and therefore it will be deflected either up or down? I was just confused because the question says which element will be deflected up and down, so does the spin just mean it could get deflected in general, and you can't predict the direction?

Comment: I misread the question - as Ivan points out the question is "which atoms are deflected at all"

Comment: That's right. Some atoms of Si will get deflected up and some down. The elements with zero net spin won't get deflected at all.

Comment: Thank you both, that makes a lot more sense. I think I was too focused about the direction, rather than just being deflected in general. I thought maybe some elements only deflected up or something, but that was quite silly in hind sight.

Comment: I was wondering why only electron spin and not kernel spin is considered in spin detection experiments. If kernels have odd proton or neutron number, they have nonzero spin. And even neutrons have magnetic momentum. Stable silver kernels have 47 protons and 60 or 62 neutrons.

Comment: @Poutnik The interaction between the nuclear spin and magnetic field is about a factor of 1000 weaker than the interaction between an electron spin and a magnetic field and one would need a very strong magnet to be able to observe a deflection.